VueJS3 filter an array props
<script setup>
import Account from "./Account.vue";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(["accounts"]);
const filteredAccounts = computed(() => {
  return props.accounts.filter((item) => parseFloat(item.Cash) != 0);
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="p-2" v-for="item in filteredAccounts">
        <Account class="" :account="item" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

The code above doesnt work if the v-for is on filteredAccounts but works fine if it is on accounts. accounts props is an array of account object.
The error I have is that the filter function is not defined :
props.accounts.filter is not a function
How can I have a computed that is filtering the prop accounts?
I try to display a filtered array based on a property

sounds like accounts prop value is initially null or undefined at the time of component creation and you need to handle this case inside your computed (can't filter on null).

Have you tried adding a key attribute to your v-for element?
It is used when looping using v-for to identify if the element should be rerendered https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes#key

Finally it appears that the object we iterate on is not an array but just a pojo and the v-for is iterating on the object key/values.

You need to make filteredAccounts into a reactive variable, for it to be fully available in the template section.


const {
  computed,
  createApp,
  ref
} = Vue;
const accounts = [{
    Cash: 1.0,
    id: 1,
    Name: 'One'
  },
  {
    Cash: 0,
    id: 2,
    Name: 'Two'
  },
  {
    Cash: 2.0,
    id: 3,
    Name: 'Three'
  },
];

createApp({
    setup() {
      const filteredAccounts = ref([]);
      filteredAccounts.value = accounts.filter((account) => parseFloat(account.Cash) != 0);
      return {
        filteredAccounts
      }
    }
  })
  .mount('#example-1');
  
  
createApp({
    setup() {
      const filteredAccounts = computed(() => accounts.filter((account) => parseFloat(account.Cash) != 0));
      return {
        filteredAccounts
      }
    }
  })
  .mount('#example-2');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-1">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="p-2" v-for="item in filteredAccounts">
      <!-- <Account class="" :account="item"/> -->
      <div>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="example-2">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="p-2" v-for="item in filteredAccounts">
      <!-- <Account class="" :account="item"/> -->
      <div>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




computed properties are inherently reactive and available to the template.  If OP wants filteredAccounts to automatically recompute based on changing dependencies (accounts), then they will want to use computed.

Added a computed example just for you @yoduh, even thou computed is overkill in this situation, and a ref work prefectly well as well.

Do you understand the purpose of computed? ref is the wrong tool to use if OP wants to automatically recompute filteredAccounts based on accounts changing, which we should assume he does if he's using computed in the first place.  Both your computed and non-computed answer change accounts from a prop to a global const, so you're not even answering the actual question which is what OP should do when the prop is initially null (the cause of their error). Your passive aggressive edit summary is also childish and unprofessional.  Be better.
